# Is there a way to use impresspages file field as a option which I can set with ipsetoption or ipgetoption

Tags: php, impresspages

I want to use a Image file to store in options of a plugin which I can use to show using ipgetoption() or set using ipsetoption(). Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two separate things together.

1. How to handle file uploads (read about forms http://www.impresspages.org/docs/form)
2. How to mark which uploaded files belong to your plugin use ipSetOption ipGetOption. But it would be much better to use storage for this http://www.impresspages.org/docs/storage